# How do I add a second menu to a page's header.php?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm trying to insert a second menu into the header file just for the front page.  The primary navbar is hidden by default and appears when the user scrolls down past the hero area.  I'm putting a another menu in the hero area of the front page that, in theory, should be taking the same data as the navbar.

Navbar works great.  Links populate correctly.  They all work.  Groovy.  The hero menu, on the other hand absolutely does not.

I registered the hero-menu in functions.php.

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in three locations.
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'Primary' => __( 'main-menu'),
            'Secondary' => __( 'footer-menu'),
            'Hero' => __('hero-menu')
        )
    );
```

The php is basically a straight copy/paste of the functional main-menu navbar, except for removing the navbar classes and changing the theme location.

```
// Navbar Menu
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-4" id="main-menu">
     <?php
         wp_nav_menu(array(
              'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
              'container' => false,
              'menu_class' => '',
              'fallback_cb' => '__return_false',
              'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="text-primary navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
              'depth' => 2,
              'walker' => new bootstrap_5_wp_nav_menu_walker()
         ));                            
     ?>                     
</div>

. . . .

// Hero Menu
<div>
     <?php
          wp_nav_menu(array(
               'theme_location' => 'hero-menu',
               'container' => false,
               'menu_class' => '',
               'fallback_cb' => '__return_false',
               'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="text-primary navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
               'depth' => 1,
               'walker' => new bootstrap_5_wp_nav_menu_walker()
          ));                           
     ?>     
</div>
```

My menus are linked....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EryqD.png)

I initially tried linking my primary menu to it, and that failed.  So I thought that maybe there was a problem with the menu linking to two theme locations, so I rebuilt the main menu as a second hero menu and linked that.  Failed.  I tried stripping the args down to nothing except the theme location.  Fails.  The php function itself is working, because if I turn fallback on, it does populate with the default, but not anything I'm actually wanting to populate it with.  If I turn fallback off, it doesn't populate with anything.

Is there something here that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  If anyone else has an issue like this, explicitly setting the 'menu' arg fixed it.

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu' => 'hero-menu',
    'theme_location' => 'hero-menu',
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => '',
    'fallback_cb' => '__return_false',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="text-primary navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 1,
    'walker' => new bootstrap_5_wp_nav_menu_walker()
  ));                           
?>
```

I'm assuming that indicates the GUI menu settings aren't functioning (or at least the option to link menus), which raises the question of why they're not working, but for the moment its working now.